# Python: Selenium with Chrome Driver hanging after click

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate a search on an e-commerce using selenium with chrome driver, from the first url, type the search, click on the search button, return the next url and that's it.

But after clicking, the next page won't load and I can't figure out why.

the code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

def open():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

    drive = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    url = 'https://www.extra.com.br/'
    drive.get(url)

    busca = drive.find_element_by_id('ctl00_TopBar_PaginaSistemaArea1_ctl05_ctl00_txtBusca')
    busca.send_keys('Informática')

    botao_buscar = drive.find_element_by_id('ctl00_TopBar_PaginaSistemaArea1_ctl05_ctl00_btnOK')
    botao_buscar.click()

    return drive.current_url

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(open())
```

I've tried just opening the second url directly (without the form submit) and it works.

Comment: To be clear, the busca.send_keys() works properly but the click does not?

Comment: both work, but the next page won't load, i just get a blank page

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of chromedriver and selenium?

Comment: yes, just checked

Comment: What operating system are you using? Sometimes linux has issues with chromedriver if it is a newer version if that is what you are using.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: Try using these two pages and hopefully it can help you. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: The site you are trying to scrape is blocking all automated software...